# Specify installation directory in Cygwin installer

Tags: cygwin, setup

I want to automatically install Cygwin using a batch file.

I got the command like this until now:

```
setup-x86.exe --packages rsync -l "F:/v2.0/cygwin/packages" -L
```

The setup options can be viewed like this:

```
setup-x86.exe --help
```

I am a little confused. Because there are various options but none for the destination installation directory. It always installs to C:/cygwin and it seems it cannot be changed.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help provides an overview of all options.
In your case you are looking for:

```
$ ./setup-x86_64.exe --help | grep Root
 -R --root                         Root installation directory
```